# Change keyboard layout for a specific input in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: keyboard-layout, ibus

In Text Entry settings, I have two input sources: French and Vietnamese. 
The problem is, the French input uses an azerty layout (like the physical keyboard of my laptop) while the Vietnamese input uses an qwerty one, which is very annoying.

Could anybody please tell me how to either set a fixed keyboard layout for all input sources or set the keyboard layout of the Vietnamese input to azerty?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vietnamese seems to have only one layout you can create new custom one as "Vietnamese (qwerty)"

See [Howto: Custom keyboard layout definitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3a%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions#Creating_a_new_layout_from_scratch)

You can use Vietnamese layout as a template.

Comment: Hi Sneetsher. Thanks for the answer.
Well, maybe this is the only solution. Ubuntu 13.10 really complicates things. It was so simple in Ubuntu 13.04 and before.

Comment: @Khue, if you think this keyboard is quite needed or popular. You may submit it as patch / bug report to be included in the next releases.